# Get specific fields from Rally API for Feature

Tags: rally

I am fetching the data using below API :

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/PortfolioItem/Feature/?fetch=ObjectID,FormattedID,Name,Parent&pagesize=2000

I don't want to fetch all fields in Parent. All I need Name,FormattedID,ObjectID,Parent.ObjectID,Parent.Name of  Feature. A

```
 {
"_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
"_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
"ObjectID": blabla,
"FormattedID": "F3792",
"DirectChildrenCount": 23,
"Name": "Phase 2: Fork Messages (New flow of messages that will feed data to 8 reports for D&P)",
"Parent": {
                "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
                "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/portfolioitem/portfolio/blabla",
                "_refObjectUUID": "8fae",
                "_objectVersion": "67",
                "_refObjectName": "blabla",
                "ObjectID": blabla,
               "FormattedID": "P1ABC",
               "DirectChildrenCount": 13,
                "Name": "blabla",
                "_type": "PortfolioItem/Portfolio"
             },
"_type": "PortfolioItem/Feature"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the way the Web Services API works.  Any fields included in the fetch will be returned on any object that has them.  This is very useful for being able to hydrate fields on associated objects- Parent, Iteration, etc.